# MongoDB is accessing the same data regardless of my use of --dbpath, is this normal?

Tags: database, mongodb, directory, nosql

I'm building a very simple MongoDB to store some event listings, however I'm running into a strange issue. When I start my MongoDB using `mongod` (while in the directory C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin) and pass in my database path by using `--dbpath d:/myFile/path`, everything seems to run fine. I get some feedback saying, `Detected data files in d:/myFile/path created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.`

So it looks like `--dbpath` is working, and there is data there. However when I run `mongo` (also from C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin) I'm getting the same exact data that is located in the default data path (C:\data\db). If I launch mongod with no `--dbpath`, I get access to the same databases and collections as when I use `--dbpath d:/myFile/path`.

Am I wrong in thinking that using `--dbpath` should be accessing different databases on my local machine?

Comment: You might want to consider using a configuration file with mongod - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/.  Also, to isolate your problems and confusion regarding which files are actually in use, rename the c:\data directory to something else then try to invoke `mongod` using the ---dbpath option to verify it is not using an unexpected directory.  The theory is that mongod will not start if it cannot find the data directory - messages will print to the screen.

Comment: Excellent suggestion @barrypicker. I renamed c:/data to something arbitrary and using "mongod" gave out an error saying c:/data did not exist (as expected). I once again used "--dbpath d:/myFile/path", which made mongod work correctly, and again while using "mongo" was able to access all databases, regardless of their directory location. You are probably right that I might just need to change my config file.